# Il est très peu probable que quelqu’un / un des élèves ose franchir le seuil

Tags: pronoms

Bonjour,

Plusieurs Français m'ont dit que "quelqu'un des" n'est pas naturel. Par exemple, la phrase suivante ne serait pas naturelle :

> Il est très peu probable que **quelqu’un des** élèves ose franchir le
> seuil.

Pourtant, j'ai vu l'emploi de "quelqu’un des" sur le site de la [BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3437).

> **Quelques-uns de** mes amis vont au théâtre ce soir.
>
> **Quelqu’un des** jeunes artistes que Richard fréquente l’a invité à son
> vernissage.

D'après vous, est-ce que ma phrase est correcte ou non ?

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=quelqu%27un+des&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cquelqu%27un%20des%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Quelques amis à moi vont etc. Quelques jeunes artistes que Richard fréquente etc. Au moins dans le langage parlé ordinaire...

Comment: « ***Quelques-uns de*** mes amis vont au théâtre ce soir.» tout à fait audible, « [Quelqu'] ***Un des*** jeunes artistes que Richard fréquente l’a invité à son vernissage. » On supprime *Quelqu'* sans que la phrase perde une once de sens, l'oralité usuelle supprime les mots inutiles, désuets, compliqués et aime l'abréviation, sauf pour manier l'ironie en singeant “le beau parler” : « À mon ami, un quel-con-que de ces jeunes … » ou alors, c'est pour signifier que ce *quelqu'un* est Un Quelqu'un de très important, toute la nuance vient le l'intonation.

Answer (score 3):

D'après (le) Larousse, cet emploi est considéré comme littéraire. Il indique une personne quelconque parmi plusieurs.

> Quelqu'une de ces malheureuses victimes était méconnaissable.

L'emploi de quelqu'un au singulier suivi d'un complément partitif (quelqu'un de ces maux, quelqu'une de ces langues) appartient au registre soutenu.

Voir : https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/quelqu_un/65621

Ceci pourrait expliquer pourquoi des locuteurs natifs disent qu'il ne paraît pas naturel.

Comment: Merci, les  locuteurs natifs auraient pu me dire que ce tour est littéraire, non ? Toujours bizarre, à mon avis...

Comment: @Oreste C'est 'mes deux cents' . Une conjecture:-)! Je ne suis pas natif pour l'affirmer. Ce que je peux affirmer c'est que pas mal de mon entourage natif maitrise plus que suffisamment la langue grâce à leur expérience, mais ils/elles ne sont pas à l'aise avec les explications. Ils/elles t'ont dit que ça n'est pas naturel mais ils/elles n'ont pas l'envie de chercher pourquoi comme toi ou moi. C'est normal je trouve.

Comment: Oui, je sais. Mais toujours, si quelqu'un me posait une question semblable en russe, je lui dirais que, habituellement, on ne parle pas de la sorte mais que l'on peut trouver cette expression dans des livres.

Comment: @Oreste Ça depend, je crois, de la personne. Je pense qu'il existe natifs du russe qui appliquent correctement les règles de leur langue maternelle sans qu'ils puissent expliquer toutes les règles

Comment: @Oreste Les natifs du français peuvent connaître grâce à leur exposé à la langue depuis leur enfance des règles comme l'accord du participé passé et les verbes qui sont conjugués aux temps composés avec être mais ils n'ont pas le besoin de se plonger dans la grammaire/syntaxe comme certains élèves du FLE le font. Toujours normal pour moi.

Comment: @Oreste *Quelqu'un de mes élèves* est très soutenu mais peut se lire ou s'entendre alors que *quelqu'un des élèves ose* est "trop soutenu" pour être honnête. On ne peut que penser à une erreur tellement la forme est improbable.

Comment: @jlliagre Ah, OK, dommage, j'aime bien cette formule... Mais pourquoi alors _Quelqu’un des jeunes artistes que Richard fréquente l’a invité à son vernissage._ est possible selon la BDL ? // Dimitris, je suis d'accord, moi non plus je ne connais pas la grammaire russe, et je ne pourrai pas expliquer grand-chose à ce sujet, mais je suis tout à fait capable de distinguer les tours littéraires des expressions érronées. Mais cela n'a guère d'importance...

Comment: @Oreste La formule de la BDL passe mieux probablement parce que ce qui suit *quelqu'un* est plus long, mais je ne l'emploierais quand même jamais spontanément. je dirais plutôt *L'un des jeunes artistes...* ou *Quelqu'un, parmi les jeunes artistes...*

Comment: @jlliagre Peut-être que cette formule serait acceptable au Québec ?... Il faudrait attendre l'avis de Québécois, peut-être.

Comment: @jlliagre J'ai trouvé ! Antidote : Quelqu’un de : VIEILLI – une personne parmi plusieurs. _Quelqu’un de mes amis t’a vu hier_.

Comment: @Oreste Oui, mais ne met pas dans le même sac *quelqu'un **de*** et *quelqu'un **des***. Comme je l'ai écrit plus haut, le premier ne pose pas de problème, c'est le deuxième qui ne passe pas.

Comment: J'ai trouvé un exemple d'un "grand auteur" : *Avec précaution, de crainte que **quelqu’un des** deux blessés ne fût endormi, je montai par l’étroit escalier de bois qui menait au premier étage*. Alain Fournier, *Le grand Meaulnes*, 1913. Pas de doute donc, c'est bien une forme littéraire admise.

Comment: @Oreste La forme n'est pas "acceptable" non plus au Québec. C'est littéraire, donc ça rajoute un style hors norme et ça saute fortement aux yeux. À moins que ce soit l'effet recherché, c'est à éviter. La raison est simple, pour le singulier on peut simplement utiliser "un des" alors que pour le pluriel il faut le conjuguer "quelques-uns".

Answer (score 1):

Cette question porte sur deux  acceptions de l'adjectif indéfini « quelque ».

**un petit nombre** : Quelques-uns de mes amis

**quelconque** : quelqu’un des élèves ose, Quelqu’un des jeunes artistes

Le premier est courant, sans problèmes, en déclin, mais avec toujours une forte fréquence.

[image]

[ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=quelques-uns+de&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cquelques%20-%20uns%20de%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cquelques%20-%20uns%20de%3B%2Cc0)

Le second est un usage qui est sur la fin d'un déclin régulier depuis 1800, et qui est très peu utilisé, mais qui récemment a donné signe d'un léger regain, comme il a pu le faire tout au long de sa chute vers l'obsolescence.

[image]

[ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=quelqu%27une+des&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cquelqu%27une%20des%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cquelqu%27une%20des%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

[ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=quelqu%27un+des&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cquelqu%27un%20des%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cquelqu%27un%20des%3B%2Cc0)

Cet usage est correct, mais il n'appartient pas à la langue parlée ; de plus dans la langue écrite il se fait de plus en plus rare et les écrivains hésitent à s'en servir. Personnellement, si j'en venais à l'utiliser j'aurais une certaine appéhension de risquer de ne pas être compris.

**Quelques exemples de phrases contenant ces formes**

*quelqu'une des*

[réf. 1, 1845](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Explication_des_saintes_r%C3%A8gles_et_const/6lpVm7j1u0AC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22quelqu%27une+des%22&pg=PA197&printsec=frontcover)

[réf. 2, 1861](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Dictionnaire_des_synonymes_de_la_langue/ENyEAAAAIAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22quelqu%27une+des%22&pg=PA909&printsec=frontcover)

[réf. 3, 2009](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/La_Biblioth%C3%A8que_de_Warburg_Version_mixt/snArT0b2N7AC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22quelqu%27une+des%22&pg=PT35&printsec=frontcover)

*quelqu'un des*

[réf. 4, 1812](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Repertoire_universel_et_raisonn%C3%A9e_de_ju/LlJDAAAAcAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22quelqu%27un+des%22&pg=PA208&printsec=frontcover)

[réf. 5, 1832](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Journal_des_connaissances_usuelles_et_pr/76k3AAAAYAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22quelqu%27un+des%22&pg=PA89&printsec=frontcover)

[réf. 6, 2021](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Litt%C3%A9rature_et_Philosophie_m%C3%AAl%C3%A9es/BGMtEAAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22quelqu%27un+des%22&printsec=frontcover) Ce livre, qui ne peut offrir d’ailleurs quelque intérêt qu’aux personnes qui aimeraient à voir de quelle façon et à quel point un esprit loyal peut se transformer par la critique de lui-même, dans nos temps de révolution sociale et intellectuelle, ce livre est le complément nécessaire et naturel de la série des œuvres de l’auteur. Chacune des sections qu’il renferme correspond à l’un des termes de cette série ; chacun de ces morceaux a été écrit en même temps que quelqu’un des ouvrages qui la composent, et représente, pour qui sait bien voir, le même groupe d’idées.

Voici ce que LBU fournit sur le second usage;

> § **758 2°**
> Dans la langue littéraire, quelqu'un s'emploie aussi au singulier,
> pour désigner, comme l'un, un représentant non précisé de l'ensemble
> mentionné avant ou après (surtout comme noyau d'un complément
> prépositionnel de quelqu'un).
>
> ♦ L'oiseau qui [...] rapportait au ciel [...] QUELQU'UN de ces monstres [serpents, etc.] (MICHELET, Insecte, X).
> ♦ Si quelqu'un, homme ou femme, commet QUELQU'UN de tous les péchés qui causent un préjudice au prochain [...] (Bible,
> trad. CRAMPON, Nombres, V, 6).
> ♦ En passant [...] sous QUELQU'UN de ces portiques sacrés (LOTI, MME Chrysanth., XXI).
> ♦ La faim de QUELQU'UN de ces animaux que nous avons domestiqués (GLDE Journal, 1.1, p. 809).
> ♦ Elle lui demanda s'il n'avait pas trouvé [...] QUELQU'UNE de ces personnes, auxquelles il s'adressait le plus volontiers (FRANCE, Lys rouge, XVII).
> ♦ je devinais QUELQU'UNE de ces occupations où je ne pouvais suivre Gilberte (PROUST, Rech., 1.1, p. 406).
> ♦Il m'arrive souvent de sourire aimablement à QUELQU'UNE de ces enfants (LÉAUTAUD, Petit ami, I).
> ♦ Il avait laissé là-bas un gamin qu'il payait vingt sous par
> jour, à tâche de surveiller le passage des autos et de l'avertir si QUELQU'UNE s'arrêtait (AYMÉ, Gustalin, IX).
> ♦ Il y en [= des enfants] avait dans les plis de sa robe,
> d'autres sur le dossier de son fauteuil qui jouaient au trapèze, QUELQU'UN presque sous son bonnet (JOUHANDEAU, Prudence Hautechaume, 1980, p. 150).

Comment: Merci. Lu dans Antidote : Quelqu’un de : VIEILLI – une personne parmi plusieurs. _Quelqu’un de mes amis t’a vu hier_.

Comment: @LPH J'aimerais bien que tu donnes de vrais exemples de *quelqu'un des* et *quelqu'une des*, au delà de courbes qui vont considérer par exemple *dire à quelqu'un des vérités désagréables*.

Comment: @jlliagre Je ne devrais pas avoir à faire ça puisque les exemples donnés par le LBU sont exactement de cette sorte. Néanmoins, je vais en ajouter quelques-uns à partir des livres Google, en particulier, deux qui sont récents.

Comment: @LPH Euh ? Non. Aucun des exemples du LBU que tu as cités n'utilise "quelqu'un **des**" ou "quelqu'une **des**".

Comment: @jlliagre Pas exactement, mais c'est pareil : « de ces ».

Comment: C'est toi qui dit que c'est pareil, je ne partage pas du tout cette opinion.

Comment: @jlliagre « Quelqu'un des » c'est « quelqu'un de les » ; ce qui compte c'est le « de ».  C'est le même dans les deux cas.

Comment: Mets de vrais exemples, pour l'instant, le seul que tu as transcrit est un faux positif. *en même temps que quelqu’un des ouvrages...*, ça n'est pas très sérieux...

Comment: @jlliagre Ah non, il n'y a pas un seul faux positif ; dans tous les cas la forme est entière et le sens de « quelque » est bien « un(e) quelconque ».

Comment: OTAN pour moi, d'accord, mais la date de 2021 est celle de la publication de la réédition scannée par Google, le texte original a semble-t-il été écrit en mars 1834.

Comment: @jlliagre C'est vraiment Hugo qui écrit ça ? Il me semble que c'est un autre auteur (moderne) qui parle de lui.

Comment: Il est impossible que ce soit Victor Hugo qui ait écrit ça. J'ai quand même trouvé ce texte dans une édition datée de 1934, 2021 est donc toujours exagéré. Mais tu as raison, on trouve bien des usages de *quelqu'un des* avec le sens attendu. *I stand corrected.*